# jQuery: Descendant selectors only working on one "hidden" div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

Hi guys maybe you can help. 
I'm building a simple tabbed form using the standard jQuery UI.  For a variety of reasons this form will have ~40 hidden divs with all form fields within (I cant have this load via AJAX).

I've created [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4EssX/) with a heavily stripped down version of the page.  You will see under the "Admin" tab a few things, but nothing will show under the management nor clinical tab. An inspection of the HTML will show that there is indeed content in there however.

This particular code that may be causing the issue is this, specifically the CSS descendant selectors:

```
    jQuery( '.tabDiv ul li a' ).click(function() {                  /* Create Toggle Function */
    var link = $(this).attr('href'); 
    jQuery( '.navigation' ).removeClass("active").addClass("hidden");
    jQuery( link ).removeClass("hidden").addClass("active");
    return false;
});
```

But if it is I can't see why.  This page will always run on the latest Chrome browser, so any IE/Firefox issues can be ignored.

Thanks in advance for any help, I've learnt a LOT off this site in a very short amount of time.

Comment: Works just fine in Safari and Chrome.

Comment: It does on the first tab (Admin), the other tabs (Clinical/management) and their child links return nothing however.

Comment: The href of those links is like "#managementBanking" which is the same as the jQuery selector for the relevant div.  That part is working fine.  Although it is a bit misleading, I hope in the actual code there are comments about that :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem is that the text appears **below** the menu, instead of to the right.  Also, only the first 2 items under Management tab have any content.

Comment: No, because I'm pointing out the problem that is occurring.  It just wasn't the problem he thought he was having.

Comment: Oh wow; I apologise for wasting every single persons time on here.

Comment: LOL, take a break, look away from the screen for a while :-)